# How to make subdomain point to a custom folder with Laravel installed in the root?

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes, subdomain

I have Laravel installed in public_html folder and I have a subdomain `x.example.com` when I open it, I get `This site can’t be reached` and when I navigate to `example.com/x` it worked. How to make the subdomain point or map to this path and ignore Laravel routing? I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/x/
RewriteRule (.*) /x/$1 [L]
```

before Laravel redirection

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can point your route or group of routes to a subdomain like this:

```
Route::domain('x.example.com')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', fn() => 'It works');
});
```